# How to fix the unresolved dependency in the Flag module about Flag Friend?

Tags: 7, updating, flags

I am trying to update my modules and I am getting this error line:

> Fatal error: Class 'RulesEventHandlerEntityBundle' not found in
>   /home1/kctd/public_html/community/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/node.rules.inc
>   on line 147.

I am in the Update.PHP screen (see photo near the bottom) and I have a few unresolved dependencies. I would normally retro install some of those modules, but when I try to check manually, or even go to my modules screen, I get the error listed above. I am locked out.

What should I do?

[image: How my update screen looks like right now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your "unresolved dependency" error messages, you are currently using the 2.2 version of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. While the [Flag Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_friend) module requires the 2.1 version of it.

It's worth trying to replacing the entire flag folder in your modules directory as follows:

- backup your flag module folder (to somewhere outside your Drupal root).
- delete the flag module folder and its entire content.
- download the [7.x-2.1 release of the flag module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1990776) and unpack that version in the very same "flag" module folder.

Then try again and see if that helps. If not restore your backup directory (to try some other approach).